# Trying to replicate IBM Mainframe SFTP upload with JSch ChannelSftp

Tags: sftp, jsch, mainframe

I am trying to use Jsch Sftp Channel to upload a file to an IBM Mainframe, and the directory has to be "//", where the mainframe will automatically route the file where it needs to go.

In an sftp command session on the IBM mainframe, I can do this:

```
sftp myuser@1.2.3.4
connecting to 1.2.3.4...
myuser@1.2.3.4's password:
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /users/home/myuser
sftp> cd //
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: //
sftp> put "#12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx"
uploading #12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx to //#12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx
#12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx               100%  403   0.4KB/s 00:00
```

So I created a JSch sftp session (version 0.1.5.1) to attempt the same upload, but it does not work:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("myuser", "1.2.3.4");
session.setPassword("mypass");
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();

ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
log.info(" user home pwd " + sftp.pwd());  //prints /users/home/myuser
sftp.cd("//")
log.info(" pwd after cd " + sftp.pwd()); //only prints /
sftp.put(filename);   //get sftp error, no such file
```

So I cannot get to that // structure through the JSch library.  Is there a certain mode or flag that needs to be set for the sftp session to know it's on a mainframe?

I have no issue at all doing a JSch sftp session to my /users/home/myuser directory, just can't get it to go to the //

Comment: Doesn't "No such file" mean there is a problem with `filename`? Anyway, don't you have a bunch of technical support people you can ask? People at your site who've done the same thing? A program spec?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a FTP-server running on our z/OS, so I can't play around a bit. Trying a wild guess: have you tried using an "absolute" filename like `//#12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx` instead of `cd`-ing to your z/OS filesystem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @piet.t I've tried as many variations as I can think of, but the sftp session will not recognize that // directory

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact output of your manual transfer and your attempted programmatic transfer (exact except for sensitive information)? What did your techies say?

Comment: I finally got ahold of the IBM mainframe system people, but could still not find a way to use JSch SftpChannel to get the file where I needed it to be.  What I finally decided to do was sftp the file to my home directory, and then create an exec channel to move the file.  So a mv command like `mv ./SMPL.DATA  "//'SMPL.DATA'"` is what finally worked in the JSch exec channel

Comment: The answer seems to support @piet.t in their wild guess... Did you try that already? Can you update your question with information since discovered and which belongs there (the edit link under your question) and if the answer by Kenster doesn't work, put up your own "self-answer" with your workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with pseudofolder "//".
Avoid this `sftp.cd("//")` and better try this `sftp.put("/-/"+filename);` instead, that solved my problem. Hopefully will help you as well.

Comment: I had exact same issue and using sftp.get("/-/remoteFileName", "localFileName") did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without calling `ChannelSftp.cd()`:

```
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
sftp.put("//" + filename);  // Put to //#12345.abcdef.xxx.xxx
```

The SFTP protocol doesn't actually have a chdir-type operation. At the protocol level, pathnames which don't start with "/" are always interpreted relative to the directory where the SFTP session started. There's no protocol command to change that starting directory.

SFTP clients, including Jsch, emulate chdir-like behavior client-side. When you call `ChannelSftp.cd()`, Jsch stores the new remote directory locally. When you later call `put()` or `get()`, and give a pathname that doesn't start with "/", Jsch prepends the remote directory onto the filename and passes the altered name to the remote server.

I think what's happening to you is that Jsch's chdir emulation is being a little too clever. When you call `cd("//")`, it's collapsing the "//" into a single "/" and storing that. Then you call `put()` for a relative pathname, it's prepending the single "/" instead of the double "//" that you want.

Based on inspecting [the Jsch source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.50/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java), it looks like Jsch never alters remote names that start with "/". If you call `put("//somefile")`, Jsch should use the name you specified as-is.